# R: Is it possible to simulate data according to the following conditions?

Tags: r, random, simulation, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. Suppose I have the following data set:

```
set.seed(123)

var_1 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 1)
var_2 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 5)
var_3 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 10)

my_data <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3)
my_data$group <- as.factor(sample(LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE, 
                                  prob=c(0.25, 0.3, 0.5, 0.15)))
my_data$id <- 1:nrow(my_data)

#       var_1     var_2     var_3 group id
# 1  9.439524  6.447967 31.988103     C  1
# 2  9.769823 11.284419 23.124130     A  2
# 3 11.558708  8.766541  7.348549     C  3
# 4 10.070508  8.262287 15.431941     C  4
# 5 10.129288  5.241907  5.856601     C  5
# 6 11.715065  9.774861  5.237531     A  6
```

I want to make the following changes to this data:

- **Condition 1:** For all rows where "group = A or group = B", randomly replace at least 10% of values for var_1 with 0 and at least 15% of values for var_2 with 0
- **Condition 2:** For all rows where "group = B or group = C", randomly replace at least 20% of values for var_1 with 0 and at least 20% of values for var_3 with 0
- **Condition 3:** For all rows where "group = A or group = C", randomly replace at least 25% of values for var_1 with 0 and at least 25% of values for var_2 with 0
- **Condition 4 (Optional):** The overall percentage of 0's in the entire data should be less than 15%

I know how to simulate individual datasets which correspond to Condition 1, Condition 2 and Condition 3:

```
#condition 1

a <- rnorm(100, 10, 1)
b <- rnorm(100, 10, 5)
c <- rnorm(100, 10, 10)

condition_1 <- data.frame(a, b, c)

perc <- c(0.1, 0.15, 0)

condition_1[] <- Map(function(x, y) {
  x[sample(seq_along(x), length(x) * y)] <- 0
  x
}, condition_1, perc)

condition_1$group <- as.factor(sample(LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace=TRUE, 
                                      prob=c(0.5, 0.5)))

#condition 2

a <- rnorm(100, 10, 1)
b <- rnorm(100, 10, 5)
c <- rnorm(100, 10, 10)

condition_2 <- data.frame(a, b, c)

perc <- c(0.2, 0, 0.2)

condition_2[] <- Map(function(x, y) {
  x[sample(seq_along(x), length(x) * y)] <- 0
  x
}, condition_2, perc)

group <- c("B", "C")

condition_2$group <- as.factor(sample(group, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.5)))

#condition 3

a <- rnorm(100, 10, 1)
b <- rnorm(100, 10, 5)
c <- rnorm(100, 10, 10)

condition_3 <- data.frame(a, b, c)

perc <- c(0.25, 0.25, 0)

condition_3[] <- Map(function(x, y) {
  x[sample(seq_along(x), length(x) * y)] <- 0
  x
}, condition_3, perc)

group <- c("A", "C")

condition_3$group <- as.factor(sample(group, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.5)))

#join all data together

final <- rbind(condition_1, condition_2, condition_3)
```

**My Question:** Instead of individually simulating each of these datasets, is there a way to take the original data (i.e. "my_data") and simulate these conditions all at once?

I realize that it is very possible that conditions might contradict each other at times - if these conditions do in fact contradict each other, do any algorithms exist that can "see" how close you can come to meeting these conditions?

Thanks!

**Extra: Visualization of Missing Data**

```
library(ggplot2)

final[final == 0] <- NA

#source for "plot_missing()" function from here: https://github.com/jevgenij-p/blog/blob/master/Missing%20Values%20Plot/MissingValues.R

plot_missing(final)
```

[image]

**References:**

- https://jev-pankov.com/2017/11/15/visualize-missing-values-in-r/

Comment: I want to clarify what you mean by contradictions. For example, conditions 1 and 3 imply that `var_1` should be replaced at a different rate. Could you explain why you are specifying these different conditions for the same column, and how you want it to be implemented?

Comment: @ kybazzi: thank you for your reply! I was just curious to  know if contradictory conditions are requested - what is the closest that can be reached

Comment: Happy to help - but sorry, I still don't understand - do you want the simulation to use 15% or 25%?